# Creating Vista-Style Folder Icons

Tags: icons, windows-vista

How can I create Vista-style folder icons with something inside the folder?

`imageres.dll` (IIRC) contains icons for the front and back of a folder, and I can put my own image between them.

However, in the icons generated by Explorer from thumbnails, and in most of the prebuilt icons, the image within the folder is 3-dimensionally rotated, so that it appears to be sticking out of the folder.

I assume that is a skew transform; doers anyone know exactly how much I should skew my image?

Note that I'm not asking how to do it in Photoshop or programmatically; I'm asking what the parameters are.

Comment: Are you trying to create those Icons under XP? because that Vista has an API to create those icons.

Comment: What is it?  I've never seen such an API.

Answer (score 2):

Your first stop regarding user interface design questions like this nowadays should probably be [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx) (also available in [PDF](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/1/9/e191fd8c-bce8-4dba-a9d5-2d4e3f3ec1d3/ux%20guide.pdf)). Of course these guidelines feature articles about [Aesthetics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511275.aspx) as well, in particular you'll find there a detailed chapter about [Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511280.aspx).

For various aspects of icon design these guidelines do in fact offer precise parameters, while for others they are at least offering value ranges or characteristics, see for example sections about [Perspective](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511280.aspx#perspective), [Light source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511280.aspx#light) and [Shadows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511280.aspx#shadows).

That said, lacking design skills myself, I don't think you'll find there dedicated parameters regarding your assumption that a single skew transform might do the trick; in fact a little more complex transformation seems to be needed to achieve the desired perspective effect as illustrated in the second example within section [Perspective](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511280.aspx#perspective): *Three-dimensional objects are represented in perspective as solid objects, seen from a low birds-eye view with two vanishing points*. (An approximation via a skew/shear transform might still be possible as per my comment below though.)

Comment: The guidelines don't address my question.

Comment: Yup, as stated (edited to stress this a bit more) - however, I think one can figure from the guidelines that there might not be a definite answer to your question: for example the second illustration from section *Perspective* and its headline (*Three-dimensional objects are represented in perspective as solid objects, seen from a low birds-eye view with two vanishing points*) seems to indicate that a single skew transform might not be enough.

Comment: That said I've been able to deduce usable parameters by inverting the operation like so: I took a Vista folder icon with embedded image and used Gimps *shear* tool (*skew* in Photoshop) to make its top border horizontal again; applying the inverse value to an image worked just fine then. Still this is only an approximation, as per my previous comment: top and bottom border are parallel rather than deduced from *two vanishing points* (just repeat the operation), in addition the parameters are size sensitive in Gimp at least, i.e. you'll have to do this for each icon size - or do the math ;)